# ForeignKey column does not select value in Kendo-Grid

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I have a grid with some columns where one of these columns is a foreignKey column.

I want to show all possible values for that column in a combobox. `ViewData["States"]` is an `IList<State>` where State has an `Id` field and a `Name` field.

To achieve that, I modified the template "GridForeignKey.cshtml" like the following:

```
@model object

@(
 Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m)        
    .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") +  
   "_Data"]).Filter(FilterType.Contains).Placeholder("Select...")
)
```

My View looks like this:

```
<div class="contentwrapper">
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    @(
    Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerModel>()    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);

        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.StateId, (IEnumerable)ViewData["States"], "Id", "Name");

        columns.Bound(p => p.StreetAddress).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Zip).EditorTemplateName("Integer");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });//edit and delete buttons
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())//add button
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))//inline edit
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
        .Ajax()                 
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => {
            model.Id(c => c.CustomerId);
            model.Field(c => c.CustomerId).Editable(false);
            model.Field(c => c.Zip).DefaultValue(4444);
        }
        )//id of customer
        .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Customer"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "Customer"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Customer"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Customer"))
    )
)
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.e`enter code here`ach(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);//show error
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Now my problems:

1. My Table does not show the selected value for "State".
2. When I edit a row, the combobox shows up and has all the desired values in it, but the value is not chosen. Instead it always shows the placeholder-text.
3. Before I had a complex object bound to my grid which had a field which was a complex type itself (`State` which contained the `Id` and `Name` attributes) but somehow kendo wouldnt let me bind it like `p => p.State.Id`. That's why I have flattened my model, and I now use the field `StateId` instead. Is it even possible to use a cascaded complex type like this?

Answer (score 3):

What you have will not work.  You need to pass the EditorTemplate the list in the EditorViewData and tell it which EditorTemplateName to use.

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.StateId, (IEnumerable)ViewData["States"], "Id", "Name")
    .EditorViewData(new { statesList = ViewData["States"] })
    .EditorTemplateName("GridForeignKey");
```

And GridForeignKey.cshtml like

```
@model int // Assuming Id is an int
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m)
    .Placeholder("Select...")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .BindTo(ViewData["statesList"])
)
```

This might not be exactly right since I just did it off the top of my head.  But it should get you in the right direction at least.

Comment: i am a little bit confused: it seems youre passing the viewdata twice?! and when i chose foreignkey-colum the GridForeignKey-Template is called implicitly. anyway, i tried what you suggested and it results in exactly the same as i had. (the problems still persist). but still thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

to achieve what you want you need to implement some client side scripts after you define the edit event in the Grid

```
 .Events(events => events.Edit("onEdit"))

if your grid called **myGrid** then your script will be in this way

<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var innerContent = $(".k-grid-delete").html().replace("Delete", "");
    $(".k-grid-delete").html(innerContent);
});

function onEdit(e) {
    $("#**myGrid** tbody [data-role=dropdownlist]").each(function () {
        var ddl = $(this).data("kendoDropDownList");
        if (ddl) {
            ddl.options.optionLabel = "Select";
            ddl.refresh();
            ddl.value("");
        }
    })
}
```